# Can I avoid military service in Latvia if I am studying at universty

Tags: military, latvia

Latvia has updated its conscription laws, stating that individuals aged 18 to 27 must undergo military service. If you're starting university soon, can you avoid conscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no, as you can see [here](https://www.mod.gov.lv/en/state-defence-service). For now, the draft is "volunteers first" with an unspecified quota, so there is a universal possibility of not being drafted. If you are under 24 and have not yet graduated but are in the education system, you are not subject to conscription.